# Not able to download touchtestagent.apk file

Tags: android, performance, mobile

I am trying to download touchtestagent.apk file from soasta server. But the apk file is not proper, it's not an executable. Please let me know the correct url to download the apk file. i tried in google play store, but it's not available there.

Please suggest if anybody has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download from the TouchTest (or CloudTest) server you are using from the Resources page. If you have a TouchTest Lite account, you can get it from here: https://touchtestlite.soasta.com/concerto/downloads/mobile/apps/android/touchtestagent/TouchTestAgent.apk

I usually download the file to my Mac and use Android SDK to install to a connected device.